# Broken keyboard wifi capability off

Tags: keyboard

Hello my compac persario cq56 has a completely busted on board keyboard. I have connected a external keyboard but the fn + f12 is not being reconized to turn on the wireless capability. The bios does not have a option to disable hotkey requirements and in windows mobility the option to enable the wifi is grayed out. I assume the system does not enable the wifi from the external since it wasn't built as internal with the same hotkey. Is there a command I can run in cms to force enable? Or maybe a application that will trick the system into believing the external keyboard is the internal?

Ps I have checked that the correct drivers are installed I downloaded them from the manufacturer site + ensured it was for ralink rt5390

Comment: If possible you could try resetting the BIOS by taking the CMOS battery out. This might reset the state of the wifi switch.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the HP Wireless Button Driver and then in device manager and expand to Network Adapters, and right click your wireless adapter and go to Properties. Then go to the Power Management tab and uncheck “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.”